# Loop til every element returns true

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have a list with ids (list). Every element of that list returns a string 'true' or 'false' as a result of an online check with wget.
I want to loop over that list, as long as there is a element returning a 'false' value.
Basically I want to repeat this:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
  wget online check
  if status == 'true':
    write id to another list
  elif status == 'false':
    continue
  time.sleep()
```

over and over again until everything is true.

I tried it with a nested while loop:

```
for j in range(len(list)):
    while status_ == 'false':
        wget online check
      if status == 'true':
        write id to another list
      elif status == 'false':
        continue
      time.sleep()
```

But that doesn't work.
Can anyone help please?

Cheers

Comment: is status always a string or could you make it a boolean?

Comment: It's always a string. To be more specific: The status is written in a file which is downloaded when the check request is sent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `deque` as a rotating queue, removing a value from the deque when it succeeds. The loop continues as long as the `deque` is not empty.

(A deque is like a list, but you can efficiently add elements to or remove elements from either end.)

```
from collections import deque

d = deque(list)

while d:
    i = d.popleft()
    wget online check
    if status == "true":
        write id to another list
    else:
        d.append(i)  # Put it back to try again later
    time.sleep(...)
```

Comment: I tried this method but i get: TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'str'. Maybe it is important to know that the IDs are strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to store a value that is set to False everytime a False is met.

```py
flag = False

while not flag:
    flag = True 
    for i in range(len(list)):
      wget online check
      if status == 'true':
        write id to another list
      elif status == 'false':
        flag = False
        continue
      time.sleep()
```

Answer (score 0):

`list` is a bad name, I think you are after `all(..)` or `any(..)`:

```
k = [True, False, False, True]
print(k)
while any(not i for i in k):   # loop as long as one value is False
    for i, v in enumerate(k):
        if not v:              # for demo purposes: change 1 False to True
            k[i] = True        
            break
    print(k)

print("done")
```

Output:

```
[True, False, False, True]
[True, True, False, True]
[True, True, True, True]
done
```

Documentation:

- [all()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)
- [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, try to put a `break` at the end of the block where you get `"true"`.

Hope it helps, have a nice day.